# Difference between multiplexer and decoder

Tags: multiplexer, decoder

What is the difference between a multiplexer and a decoder? Lets assume a 2-to-4 decoder and a 4-to-1 multiplexer, what I understand is they both select one input based on the selector's combination. Is there any scenario that a multiplexer can be replaced by a decoder and vice versa?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine any scenario where one could replace the other. None are coming to mind (except trivial cases.) The decoder sets (or clears) the sole indicated output line, out of several output lines (which then have the opposite value from the indicated line.) The multiplexer passes along the state of the indicated input, chosen from several input lines, to the only output line. Have you looked at the truth tables or the behavioral block diagrams for either of these devices?

Comment: `they both select one input based on the selector`  ... that is incorrect .... one selects an input, the other selects an output

Comment: Your question is faulty because you assert things that are wrong. Maybe if you googled the difference you would answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

A multiplexer (MUX) selects one data input from multiple sources based on a control signal, while a decoder converts a binary code into a set of mutually exclusive signals. While they both involve selecting one output among several inputs, they serve different purposes.

In some cases, you can replace a 4-to-1 MUX with a 2-to-4 decoder and additional logic, but they are not interchangeable in all scenarios due to their distinct functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Both mux and decoder are combination logic, but both serve different purposes. A mux is a digital circuit that selects one of several input data lines and directs it to single output line. The selection of input line is controlled by a set of binary select lines; the number of select lines determines the size of the mux.

A decoder is a circuit that takes a binary input and activates one of its output lines based on the input value. Mostly decoders are used to enable specific components in larger systems based on a particular input condition.

Replacing a mux with a decoder: If the mux has only one active output for a given combination of select lines it can be functionally replaced by a decoder.

Example: if you have a 4-to-1 mux where only one input is selected for each combination of select lines you could use a 2x4 decoder to achive the same functionality.

Replacing a decoder with mux:
if the decoder's output lines are used to enable or disable certain components in a system, and these components can be considered as inputs to the mux, then you might replce the decoder with a mux.

Example: if the outputs of a 2-to-4 decoder are used to enable four different components, you could replace it with a 4-to-1 mux where the components are the data input and the decoder's input is used as the select line.

Answer (score 0):

A multiplexer is a data selector. Think of it as changing the channel on an old television or radio, with each input being animal planet, nickelodeon, cartoon network, etc. You can only have one channel on your tv screen at a time, and you select the channel using the remote. A 4 to 1 decoder will have 4 channels to choose from.

Your concept of what a decoder does is wrong. A decoder serves a totally different function than a mux. It would not make much sense at all to use a decoder in place of a multiplexer. That would be almost like using a hammer to insert a screw. These are different tools for the job.

A decoder takes in a code using it's n inputs, and can output up to 2^n - 1 unique outputs. The outputs can be whatever you want them to be. That's defined in the circuit. It's very helpful to study truth tables when you're learning digital design. I found this truth table on google. Here, there's 3 inputs, A2, A1, A0, and 2^3 - 1 = 7 outputs. For every truth table there's a logic circuit that goes with it.

[image]